# TYPO3 TCA Syntax to FlexForm Syntax

Tags: php, typo3

I have the following xml: (Not my complete XML. After the selection, i have defined some settings, like OrderBy, pid etc )

```
<el>
<switchableControllerActions>
<TCEforms>
    <label>Select function</label>
    <onChange>reload</onChange>
    <config>
        <type>select</type>
        <items>
            <numIndex index="0">
                <numIndex index="0">List View</numIndex>
                <numIndex index="1">MyExt->list;MyExt->show</numIndex>
            </numIndex>
            <numIndex index="1">
                <numIndex index="0">Detail View</numIndex>
                <numIndex index="1">MyExt->show</numIndex>
            </numIndex>
            <numIndex index="5">
                <numIndex index="0">Import</numIndex>
                <numIndex index="1">--div--</numIndex>
            </numIndex>
            <numIndex index="10">
                <numIndex index="0">User Import</numIndex>
                <numIndex index="1">MyExt->import</numIndex>
            </numIndex>
        </items>
        <types>
            <numIndex index="0">
                <showItem index="0">orderBy</showItem>
                <showItem index="1">orderBy</showItem>
            </numIndex>
        </types>
    </config>
</TCEforms>
<switchableControllerActions>
</el>
```

What i would like to do, is to specify some settings to each view without these settings to be applicable to every view. For example, on the list view, i would like to have the setting "Page for the single view" but not on the detail or import view. I found this documentation: [Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Types/Index.html#examples) but i have difficulties to convert it to FlexForm syntax.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

After @Bernd Wilke πφ showed me the right direction i found the solution to my problem. This is it:

```
<pidSingle>
  <TCEforms>
    <label>Page for the single views</label>
    <displayCond>FIELD:switchableControllerActions:=:MyExt->list;ImmobilieImport->show</displayCond>
    <config>
     <type>input</type>
     <eval>trim</eval>
    </config>
  </TCEforms>
</pidSingle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need diplayconditions for your specific settings.

```
<pidSingle>
    <TCEforms>
        <label>Page for the single views</label>
        <displayCond>FIELD:el:=:1</displayCond>
        <config>
            <type>input</type>
            <eval>trim</eval>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</pidSingle>
```

see the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Columns/ColumnsDisplayCond.html)